# jboss throws Unmarshalling error: null calling signature validation web service

Tags: java, maven, jboss, cxf, wsdl2java

I send a validation request to a web service of esignature with generated code from the wsdl provided here:

https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/services/

Wsdl is the SoapDocumentValidationService.

The validation works fine with my tester executing from eclipse and with the validation service runing on an apache-tomcat-8.5.31.

But when I try to run a test from the navigator using a jboss-5.2.0 (with cxf bug solved) to deploy the app, the jboss gives an "Unmarshalling error: null" on the returning xml from the web service, presumably by incompatibility with some library or methods.

The apache doesn't have any errors, and tha validation seems normal there.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>    

  <artifactId>pluginsib-validatesignature-esginature</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.enterprise.pluginsib.validatesignature</groupId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
  <name>PluginsIB - Validate Signature - ESignature</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.enterprise.pluginsib.validatesignature</groupId>  
    <artifactId>pluginsib-validatesignature</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>   
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->  
    <version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>3.0.0.Final</version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>  
    <cxf.version>2.2.12</cxf.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
  </dependencyManagement>

  <repositories>  
    <repository>
      <id>java.net-m2</id>
      <name>java.net - Maven 2</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/java.net-m2</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>maven-nuxeo</id>
      <name>Maven Nuxeo Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- Requerim GENAPP i PLUGINSIB -->
    <repository>
      <id>github-governib-maven</id>
      <name>GitHub GovernIB Maven Repository</name>
      <url>https://governib.github.io/maven/maven/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!--<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>org.enterprise.genapp:genapp-core</artifact>
                  <includes>
                    <include>org/enterprise/genapp/common/i18n/I18N*.*</include>
                    <include>org/enterprise/genapp/common/ws/Ws*Adapter.*</include>
                  </includes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>-->

      <!--XXX<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>             
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/../../logic/src/main/resources</directory>
                  <includes>
                    <include>logicmissatges_*.properties</include>
                    <include>genapp_*.properties</include>
                    <include>portafib_genapp_*.properties</include>
                  </includes>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
              <overwrite>true</overwrite>
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>-->
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>regenerateapi</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <property>                  
          <name>regenerateapi</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <!--Java to WSDL Plugin-->
          <!--<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>generate-wsdl-esignatureValidation.wsdl</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <className>eu.europa.esig.dss.validation.SoapDocumentValidationService</className>
                  <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>                         
                  <verbose>true</verbose>
                  <frontend>jaxws</frontend>
                  <databinding>jaxb</databinding>
                  <outputFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/esignatureValidation.wsdl</outputFile>
                  <argline>-s ${basedir}/code -portname EsignatureValidationWs -address http://localhost:8080/services/soap/validation?wsdl</argline>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                  <goal>java2ws</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>-->

          <!--WSDL to Java Plugin-->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/bindings/bindings.xjc</bindingFile>
                  </bindingFiles>
                  <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                  <defaultOptions> 
                    <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
                  </defaultOptions>
                  <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                      <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/esignatureValidation.wsdl</wsdl>
                      <packagenames>
                        <packagename>org.enterprise.pluginsib.validatesignature.esignature.ws</packagename>
                      </packagenames>
                      <!--<serviceName>SoapDocumentValidationService</serviceName>-->
                    </wsdlOption>
                  </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                  <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>

          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                  <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                  <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                  <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>



        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>  
      <groupId>org.jboss.ws.cxf</groupId>  
      <artifactId>jbossws-cxf-client</artifactId>  
      <version>4.1.1.Final</version>  
      <scope>provided</scope>  
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss</groupId>
      <version>5.3.1</version>
      <artifactId>dss-validation-soap-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
      <version>1.46</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcmail-jdk16</artifactId>
      <version>1.46</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bctsp-jdk16</artifactId>
      <version>1.46</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.java.xades</groupId>
      <artifactId>jxades</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.enterprise.pluginsib.validatesignature</groupId>
      <artifactId>pluginsib-validatesignature-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

</project>
```

The error on the jboss:

```
  13:16:17,167 INFO  [STDOUT] DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: null
             Location: line 1
        13:16:17,171 WARNING [PhaseInterceptorChain] Interceptor for {http://validation.dss.esig.europa.eu/}SoapDocumentValidationServiceImplService#{http://validation.dss.esig.europa.eu/}validateSignature has thrown exception, unwinding now
        org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: null
                at

      ****(A lot of trash)****

     org.enterprise.pluginsib.validatesignature.esignature.ESignatureValidateSignaturePlugin.validateSignature(ESignatureValidateSignaturePlugin.java:231)
                at org.enterprise.plugins.validatesignature.tester.ejb.ValidateSignatureEjb.validate(ValidateSignatureEjb.java:61)
```

The fragment of the construction of the data and the validation request:

```
SoapDocumentValidationService validationService;
    {
      SoapDocumentValidationServiceImplService service;
      URL wsdl = new URL(endpoint + "?wsdl");
      service = new SoapDocumentValidationServiceImplService(wsdl);
      validationService = service.getSoapDocumentValidationServiceImplPort();
      Map<String, Object> reqContext;
      reqContext = ((BindingProvider) validationService).getRequestContext();
      reqContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint);
    }

    //Declaration of REMOTEDOCUMENT
    RemoteDocument remSign = new RemoteDocument();
    RemoteDocument doc = null;
    byte[] sigData = validationRequest.getSignatureData();

    //Signature
    if (sigData != null) {
      remSign.setBytes(sigData);
      remSign.setDigestAlgorithm(null);
      remSign.setMimeType(getMimeType(sigData));
      remSign.setName(null);

      //Signed document
      byte[] docData = validationRequest.getSignedDocumentData();
      if (docData != null) {
        doc = new RemoteDocument();
        doc.setBytes(docData);
        doc.setDigestAlgorithm(null);
        doc.setMimeType(getMimeType(docData));
        doc.setName(null);
      }
    }

    //Final object to validate "DataToValidate"
    org.enterprise.pluginsib.validatesignature.esignature.ws.DataToValidateDTO dataToValidateDTO = new DataToValidateDTO();
    dataToValidateDTO.setSignedDocument(remSign);
    dataToValidateDTO.setOriginalDocument(doc);
    dataToValidateDTO.setPolicy(null);

    //Validacio del document
    org.enterprise.pluginsib.validatesignature.esignature.ws.WsReportsDTO signatureReport;
    ValidateSignatureResponse validateSignatureResponse = new ValidateSignatureResponse();
```

Notice that this app HAS to be deployed on a jboss-5.2.0, and that the plugin that generates the code from the wsdl it's the one just below the coment:

"WSDL to Java Plugin" in the pom.xml

I am suspecting about a bug or incompaibility with jboss, or a problem with generation of the code that autmatically assigns names to classes with the same name, but I am not sure and don't know how to solve it either if it's the case.

*If someone wants the full trace of the jboss ask in the coments, the size exceeds the max number of characters allowed here. And sorry for my english.

Comment: I can't help but on this "a problem with generation of the code that autmatically assigns names to classes with the same name" it may be unlikely as in my experience - JBoss will actually spit out errors about the naming conflicts and then you have to go rename things in the WSDL to overcome the problem.  JBoss EAP 6 and 7 was well as the later wildfly's allow you to exclude subsystems such as web services and bundle your own with your application.  You might be able to just comment out the web service/web section?

Comment: Thank you for the help, at least I know it's not the names, but I am not familiar with jboss EAP 6 or 7 and anyway our apps in production phase are dropped on a jboss-5.2, so it should work on that even if jboss 6 or 7 are better. We can't touch the wsdl either since the user has to download it from the source directly (esignature). But thanks to discard the names, it's a step.

Comment: What libraries are being bundled with your EAR or WAR in the lib directory, especially any that might be CXF related?  It *might* be as simple as including the CXF related ones from tomcat in your deployment.